# Downloading most recent file using curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I need to download most recent file based on the file creation time from the remote site using curl. How can I achieve it?

These are files in remote site

```
  user-producer-info-etl-2.0.0-20221213.111513-53-exec.jar
  user-producer-info-etl-2.0.0-20221212.111513-53-exec.jar
  user-producer-info-etl-2.0.0-20221214.111513-53-exec.jar
  user-producer-info-etl-2.0.0-20221215.111513-53-exec.jar
```

Above user-producer-info-etl-2.0.0-20221215.111513-53-exec.jar is the most recent file that I want to download?  How can I achieve it?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: How are you obtaining the list of remote files?

Comment: These files are sitting in the package registry belongs to our company's gitlab page. Writing a pipeline to download the most recent file in the bash script section of the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you, file names contains dates that are alphabetically sortable !

I don't know where you are so I'm guessing you have at least a shell and I propose this bash answer:

First get the last file name

```bash
readonly endpoint="https://your-gitlab.local"

# Get the last filename
readonly most_recent_file="$(curl -s "${endpoint}/get_list_uri"|sort|tail -n 1)"

# Download it
curl -LOs curl "${endpoint}/get/${most_recent_file}"
```

You will obviously need to replace urls accordingly but I'm sure you get the idea

- `-L` : follow HTTP 302 redirects
- `-O` : download file to local dir keeping the name as is
- `-s` : silent don't show network times and stuff

you can also specify another local name with `-o <the_most_recent_file>`

for more info:

```bash
man curl
```

hth

Comment: Thanks @Boop. Getting an error when I try to most_recent_file as below.
_
kramkumar@dev-kramkumar:~$ most_recent_file="$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<XXX>" "https://<GITLAB-URL>/packages/generic/testing-packageregistry/release_1.24.9/"|sort|tail -n 1)"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    25  100    25    0     0    177      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   177
kramkumar@dev-kramkumar:~$ echo $most_recent_file
{"error":"404 Not Found"}_

Comment: mmh I indeed forgot a `-s` on the first curl. I'll update my answer. But the 404 is still a problem : are you sure the url is the correct one ? launch it first on you r shell without the `|sort|tail -n1`